# Multiple login possible in Django?

Tags: python, django

After Hosting the Django website can i login with same user name and password in multiple systems (ex: two or there systems) for that do i need to write any code

can any one help me

Answer (score 0):

You have a few options.

1. You can use Django itself as a Central Authentication Server (CAS) using a tool like django-mama-cas (https://github.com/jbittel/django-mama-cas)
2. You can use a 3rd party CAS and use it to login to Django as well as your other sites eg. Auth0 (https://auth0.com/universal-login)